# Subalgebras of certain C*-algebras

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, banach-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a C*-subalgebra of $C(X, M_{n}(\mathbb{C}))$ where $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space, does it follow that $A$ is isomorphic to  $C(Y, M_{m}(\mathbb{C}))$ for some $Y\subseteqq X$ and $m<=n$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not even even true for a singleton $X=\{\ast\}$. In this case $C(X,M_n(\mathbb{C}))\simeq M_n(\mathbb{C})$. Consider, for instance, $A$ the subalgebra of diagonal matrices. Then $A\simeq \mathbb{C}^n$. So for $n\geq 2$, this is not isomorphic to any $C(Y,M_m(\mathbb{C}))$ for $Y\subseteq X$, as the latter are isomorphic to $M_m(\mathbb{C})\not\simeq \mathbb{C}^n$.

Comment: I agree with the subalgebra of diagonal matrices. But, I am looking for a characterization result. What kind of subalgebras may it have? Is something more general known?

Comment: @user78800 My answer was rather a long comment. Your question is interesting. The keyword is $n$-subhomogeneous. See this MO [thread](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/123794/what-are-the-sub-c-algebras-of-cx-m-n).